# How to measure "whitespace" surrounding \textbullet?

Tags: fonts, white-space, bullets, measure

There is a space on both sides of `\textbullet` as well as below it, and the space is actually part of the bullet itself. Does anyone have any idea how to measure it? I want to get rid of it by using negative kern inside the box, but trial and error method isn't exactly the best way to deal with this problem.

```
\documentclass[border=5mm,varwidth=200pt]{standalone}
\begin{document}
  \newbox\circleTestBox
  \setbox\circleTestBox\hbox{\textbullet}
  \fboxsep0pt
  \fboxrule0.1pt
  textbullet: \fbox{\copy\circleTestBox}\newline
  width: \the\wd\circleTestBox\newline
  height: \the\ht\circleTestBox\newline
  depth: \the\dp\circleTestBox
\end{document}
```

[image]
[image]

ADDENDUM: By examining the output in Microsoft Paint, I can tell the white space on left and right is identical, if this helps.

Comment: you can't, this is a font glyph so the only way to get this would be by examing the glyph. If you want a circle with exact dimensions use e.g. tikz.

Comment: I can't reproduce the figures you get. I get width 5.00002pt and height 4.44444pt.

Comment: bp2017, if you open the pdf and check properties, which font is being used? I tested your example and the dimensions were as @egreg noted.

Comment: bp2017, very strange, if I add \usepackage{lmodern} to your file, I get the font that you have, but the width and height are still the same as before: width 5.00002pt and height 4.44444pt. I am surprised by your results, of course this doesn't help to answer your question. Without adding the lmodern package, the font info from the pdf states: Fonts Used in this Document CMR10 and CMSY10. (using Acrobat Reader)

Comment: bp2017, I tried compiling with XeLaTeX and reproduced your output. I was compiling with pdfLaTeX before.

Comment: I'm getting the same dimensions as OP with LuaLaTeX

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\begin{document}
\edef\gid{\the\XeTeXcharglyph"2022}
%\showthe\dimexpr\fontcharwd\font"2022
%\showthe\dimexpr\XeTeXglyphbounds1 \gid
\showthe\dimexpr\XeTeXglyphbounds3 \gid
\end{document}
```

Compile with XeLaTeX. \textbullet is described in Unicode by U+2022.
The width of \textbullet is 7.78pt (from \showthe\dimexpr\fontcharwd\font"2022)
White space on the left is 2.45pt = \showthe\dimexpr\XeTeXglyphbounds1 \gid
White space on the right is 2.45pt = \showthe\dimexpr\XeTeXglyphbounds3 \gid

So the width of the actual bullet is 2.88pt (7.78pt - 2.45pt - 2.45pt)

Comment: `\show\bullet` tells you that `\bullet=\mathchar"220F` so in the above sample doc replace `2022` by `220F`. EDIT: Actually tested this and it probably doesn't work, but not sure why?