# How can I make a text node in TikZ only as large as character extent?

Tags: tikz-pgf

Imagine I have the following code in TikZ:

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\usepackage{pagecolor}
\pagecolor{yellow}
\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[x=1mm,y=1mm]
        \node[anchor=north west,outer sep=0,inner sep=0] at (0,0) {\sffamily\TeX};
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

This creates the TeX logo, which is cropped by standalone at the top to the upper ends of the X and the lower line of the E:

[image]

However what I want to achieve is, that the text node only has the exact size of the text in the node:

[image]

Additionaly I would like to use the top left corner of the T as the anchor, so basically the north west of the T glyph. Right now as the X is higher, this becomes the north anchor.

Can both of that be achieved and if yes, how?

Comment: A side note, you do not need another package to have the yellow background `\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \node[fill=yellow,anchor=north west,outer sep=0,inner sep=0] at (0,0) {\sffamily\TeX};
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}`

Comment: Also, you may try to only write a `T` there will be some margin around of it

Comment: Thanks @BambOo, the yellow color is for illustration of the problem only. And I know, every character has a margin around it, but I want to get rid of it, this is basically my question. And I also know, that I can crop a PDF, but I need it for placement of a node, so it needs to be within ``TikZ`` and I just wanted to illustrate it with a simple enough example.

Comment: While it is possible to determine the width of a single character (including while space), and it is possible to crop a known width, I know of no way to determine how much of a font character is actually white space.

Comment: @TobiBS what I meant (and was confirmed by John Kormylo) is that the white space is part of the glyph. Could you provide more context so we understand the need for such precision ?

Comment: I want to typeset an Icon according to a specification. This specification gives you rules like a whitespace between the next element and text. Hence I want to place the edge of the text precisely to a coordinate that has the given distance. And I thought that maybe on a micro level, this is achievable with LaTeX, too. Right now my solution is to manually fiddle the coordinate until it looks as it is supposed to with additional helper lines.

Comment: I think [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/516610/194703) is related.